# Kafka EC2: Configuration issue with "advertised.listeners" and "listeners"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

We have Kafka running in EC2 instances with the below server.properties:

```
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=10

# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
# add all 3 zookeeper instances ip here
zookeeper.connect=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181,ip4:2181,ip5:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

#Addition of listeners

listeners=EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:36379,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://our-external-endpoint:36379,INTERNAL://ec2-hostname:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

We have to access the brokers from outside the EC2 network, for that we have one endpoint for each broker(configured with NLBs to point to the actual brokers).We are able to telnet to the actual brokers form our endpoint.Even we are able to get the metadata using our external endpoint as bootstrap servers as below:

```
kafkacat -b our-external-endpoint:36379 -L 
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: our-external-endpoint:36379/bootstrap):
 6 brokers:
  broker 10 at compute1.internal:9092
  broker 20 at compute2.internal:9092 (controller)
  broker 40 at compute3.internal:9092
  broker 30 at compute4.internal:9092
  broker 50 at compute5.internal:9092
  broker 60 at compute6.internal:9092
 4 topics:
  topic "from_ec2" with 1 partitions:
  ...
```

But we are getting the actual internal hostnames instead of the external one.In ZkCli we can see the following data:

```
get /brokers/ids/10
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"EXTERNAL":"PLAINTEXT","INTERNAL":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["EXTERNAL://our-external-endpoint:36379","INTERNAL://compute1.internal:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"our-external-endpoint","timestamp":"1575456980136","port":36379,"version":4}
```

So, there is no issue with our endpoint configuration since we are able to get the metadata using our endpoint.Then must be something wrong with the configuration, we have tried combinations like having only one value in `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092)` and `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://our-external-endpoint:36379` but no luck.To produce/consume from our outside EC2 network, I think in the metadata our external point should be returned as the internal EC2 hostname is not accessible from our external network.What are we missing here?

Comment: How is your load balancer configured? What happens if you try to connect to the EC2 instance directly instead of via the LB? I'd take that out of the equation first.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt We are able to create/consume/produce data directly from the EC2 instance, no issues there.For example, we are able to consume using this:```./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic from_ec2 --from-beginning ``` .Regarding LB:our_endpoint -> LB ->target group, the target group is pointing to the actual EC2 broker IP and port (9092).Then the endpoint external port(36379) is whitelisted from our network.I don't suspect any issues with the endpoint connectivity here since we are able to hit the broker and get the metadata.Was referring to your blog only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> the [load balancer's] target group is pointing to the actual EC2 broker IP and port (9092)

In effect you're forwarding your external traffic to the internal (9092) listener. With a LB you could have any external port if you wanted - the key here is the point at which the network traffic hits the Kafka broker. If the traffic from your LB is hitting the brokers on 9092 then the brokers are using the *internal* listener than you've defined.

Change your LB to route traffic to your **external** listener, port `36379`

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ (which I know you've seen, but will help others discovering this answer)

Comment: Thanks, exactly this was the issue.I was under the impression clients will try to connect to each of the endpoints mentioned in the "advertised.listeners" one by one, clearly misunderstanding at my end.